# Executing a common method after each Promise.then function

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I'm developing a nodejs app and using bluebird.js - Promise. I have a method which I want to be called after each .then() method being executed in the chain. Is there a way (or API) that supports this in bluebird.js?

Thanks.

Comment: For `new Promise(...).then(...).then(...).then(...);`, are you expecting your method to be called 3 times ?

Comment: No.  There is no built-in way to do that and to even try to hack it in by patching `Promise.prototype.then()` would be fairly complicated.  Please describe the real problem you're trying to solve so we can perhaps offer a supported way to solve whatever your real problem is.

Comment: Are you trying to get your method called after each `.then()` is called?  Or after each `resolveHandler` or `rejectHandler` that was passed to the `.then()` is called?  Those are two very different things as the `resolveHandler` or `rejectHandler` are called long after `.then()` is called.

Comment: Hi, please take a look at the bluebird monitoring API: https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/pull/997/files it's not really documented yet but it should do what you're asking for.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is your [actual problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)? Decorating `.then` is probably not the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the bluebird monitoring API for this.

```
Promise.config({
  monitoring: true
});
```

Listen to the `promiseChained` event to detect the `then` is chained and then listen to the `promiseFulfilled` event to know when the callback has executed:

```
var candidates = new WeakSet(); // a set for our promises that were chained
process.on('promiseChained', (_, {promise, child}) => {
    candidates.add(child);
});
process.on('promiseFullfilled', (_, {promise}) => {
    if(candidates.has(promise)) {
       callYourFunctionHere(); // HERE  
    }
});
```

This will execute on *every* `then` handler executed, if you want to execute it for a *specific* then, before adding to candidates - check if `promise` (the argument) is the promise chained to or it's in the set (so it's part of the chain).

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a special callback for each then. For example:

Lets say you have 3 different callbacks to use on the "then"s.

```
function callbackA() {
  console.log('A');
  return Promise.resolve();
}
function callbackB(hello) {
  console.log('B',hello);
  return Promise.resolve();
}
function callbackC() {
  console.log('C');
  return Promise.resolve();
}

//Then you have your "then" handler:

function handler(cb, context, params) {
    context = context || this;
  params = params || [];
  //Do your "on-every-then stuff
  console.log("It's a THEN!!!");
  //Then run your desired callback
  return cb.apply(context, params);
}

//And your main code:
callbackA()
  .then(handler(callbackB, this, ["there"]))
  .then(handler(callbackC));
```

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/59na19h7/).